# Sock Server and Client

Tags: perl, socks

I have the following Socks Server

```
my $socks_server = IO::Socket::Socks->new(
  ProxyAddr   => "localhost",
  ProxyPort   => 8000,
  Listen      => 1,
  ) or die "socket error";
 
while(1) {
  my $client = $socks_server->accept();
  print $client;
  unless ($client) {
    print "ERROR:";
    next;
  }
}
```

and the following Socks Client

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::Socks;
 
my $socks_client = IO::Socket::Socks->new(
  ProxyAddr   => "localhost",
  ProxyPort   => "8000",
) or die $SOCKS_ERROR;
 
print $socks_client "foo\n";
$socks_client->close();
```

the Socks client print "foo\n" , how can I let the Socks Server print it to the console when its received?

Comment: The `accept` function returns a socket object, not the string you sent. Read the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::Socks) for the module.

Comment: how can i read the string i sent?

Comment: `send` and `recv`?

Answer (score 2):

Following code is provided for demonstration purpose only, authentication is turned off for simplicity.

The code is based on documetation for [IO::Socket::Socks](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::Socks)

Code for **server.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use IO::Socket::Socks ':constants';

my $SOCKS_ERROR = 'Error: SOCKS';
 
my $socks_server = IO::Socket::Socks->new(
  ProxyAddr   => "localhost",
  ProxyPort   => 8000,
  Listen      => 1,
  UserAuth    => \&auth,
  RequireAuth => 0
) or die $SOCKS_ERROR;
 
while(1) {
  my $client = $socks_server->accept();
   
  unless ($client) {
    print "ERROR: $SOCKS_ERROR\n";
    next;
  }
 
  my $command = $client->command();
  if ($command->[0] == CMD_CONNECT) {
     # Handle the CONNECT
     $client->command_reply(REPLY_SUCCESS, 'localhost', 8000);
  }
   
  print while <$client>;
   
  $client->close();
}
 
sub auth {
  my ($user, $pass) = @_;
   
  return 1 if $user eq "foo" && $pass eq "bar";
  return 0;
}
```

Code for **client.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use IO::Socket::Socks;
 
my $socks_client = IO::Socket::Socks->new(
  ProxyAddr   => "localhost",
  ProxyPort   => "8000",
  ConnectAddr => "localhost",
  ConnectPort => "8022",
) or die $SOCKS_ERROR;
 
print $socks_client $_ for <DATA>;

$socks_client->close();

__DATA__
-----------------------------------------------
This a test message sent from remote client for
SOCKS demonstration code.

Enjoy your day.
```

Output on **server.pl** side

```
C:\....\examples\socks_server.pl
-----------------------------------------------
This a test message sent from remote client for
SOCKS demonstration code.

Enjoy your day.
```

Output on **client.pl** side

```
C:\...\examples\socks_client.pl
C:\...>
```

Comment: Setting `UserAuth => &auth` when `RequireAuth` is set to 0 is a bit pointless

Comment: @Dada -- feel free to set it to `1` and implement **Authentication** mechanism.